# xmllint content truncated after parsing xpath expression

Tags: text, xpath, xmllint

I am running the following xmllint command but I get truncated content.

echo xpath '//create_context[@date="2013-01-31"]/instrument/file/text()' | xmllint --shell file.xml

/ > Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 3 nodes:

1  TEXT

```
content=/algodata/nysealmdev1/TOP/dynamic.201306...
```

2  TEXT

```
content=/algodata/nysealmdev1/TOP/dynamic.201306...
```

3  TEXT

```
content=/algodata/nysealmdev1/TOP/dynamic.201306...
```

my xmllint doesn't take --xpath as a parameter

Thanks for your help and sorry if someone already provided an answer.

Comment: Welcome on SO. It fine to post a more specific problem that you have even if something similar has been asked elsewhere as long as you searched for it and it doesn't solve your problem! :) You could have a look to our Help section : http://stackoverflow.com/help if you haven't got the chance :) Good luck

Comment: This is a really good question. I'm looking for the solution too.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this :-(

Answer (score -1):

xmllint --shell isn't really designed to extract data. If you want to use XPath to extract stuff from an XML file on the command line, try XMLStarlet: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//create_context[@date='2013-01-31']/instrument/file/text()" file.xml
```